# Converting SQL with group by and having to linq

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have this SQL Server Query that I need to convert into Linq, could someone help me?

```
select 
    count(*) Cuantas,
    v.IdLote, 
    right(m.NumTarj, 6) Term, 
    max(m.FechaMovimiento) as UltimaDisp, 
    m.NumCta, m.NombreTarj, m.LimiteCredito, m.DisposicionATM
from 
    Validacion v 
join 
    Movimientos m on m.NumeroTarjeta = v.NumeroTarjeta
where 
    v.FechaEnvioCredencial is not null
group by   
    v.IdLote, right(m.NumTarj, 6), m.NumCta, m.NombreTarj, m.LimCred, m.DispATM
having  
    count(*) >1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert your sql query to linq using [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) or [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)